# What happens with the site self-evaluation results

Tags: discussion

Will the results of the site self-evaluation be posted on the site? Where can I find more information about the self-evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll repost this, since [Anna Lear](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/anna-lear) already [provided an answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166701/166017). Basically, yes, the plan is that you will be able to see the results of the self-evaluation.

> When an evaluation completes, we're going to post the result summary
>   as an answer on the [automated meta
>   post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166562/155160) that will be
>   created at the start of the evaluation.
>
> It will look something like this, though formatted in a way that is
>   allowed in answers (i.e. probably without the pretty table):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Laura, will be good to see how we're doing! I've been tracking the Area51 stats all along, and seems to be strong so far.

Comment: Where can I find this automated meta-post?